# Change v-model data in parent's methods

Tags: vuejs2, modal-dialog, daterangepicker

I'm using custom modal vue2 component that used to open jQuery bootstrap modal. I need to use my custom datepicker in that modal with modified start date for each modal (like create/edit events in the calendar).

But this datepicker model is not changing its model value in parent component's methods, and we can just initiate/change it in `created` method.

HTML:

```
<div id="modal_calendar" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg  modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <date-picker-calendar
                    placeholder="Select Date Range..."
                    v-model="calendarDate">
                </date-picker-calendar>                  
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Scripts:

```
<script>
formModal = new Vue({
    el:'#modal_calendar',
    data:{
        calendarDate: '',
        form:{
            start_date:'',
            end_date:'',
        },
    }
    components: {
        'date-picker-calendar': datePicker
    },
    methods:{
        show:function (form) {
            $(this.$el).modal('show');
           
            // THIS IS NOT WORKING!!! Dates are for testing...
            // I NEED TO CHANGE THIS MODEL VALUE (COMPONENT DATA) Here!
            this.calendarDate = ['2022/10/05', '2022/10/10'];
            
        },
    }
    created:function () {
        // THIS IS JUST WORKING ONCE!!!
        this.calendarDate = ['2022/10/05', '2022/10/10'];
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to a on-click event on the modal and emit a custom event. Then, the parent component can listen to that event and update a variable (prop) on the parent component.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#event-arguments